# Why is the GUI components obsolete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm currently making a remake of Dreadhalls in Unity3D. I got the code but I got 2 errors:

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\ForcedReset.cs(6,27): error CS0619: 'GUITexture' is obsolete: 'GUITexture has been removed. Use UI.Image instead.'
```

```
Assets\Standard Assets\Utility\SimpleActivatorMenu.cs(10,16): error CS0619: 'GUIText' is obsolete: 'GUIText has been removed. Use UI.Text instead.'
```

I tried replacing them with the items given to me in the error, but it is still getting errors saying that the namespacee name UI is not found. I'm still not used to Unity so I need some help.

Here is the code of `ForcedReset.cs`:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

[RequireComponent(typeof (GUITexture))]
public class ForcedReset : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        // if we have forced a reset ...
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("ResetObject"))
        {
            //... reload the scene
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneAt(0).name);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of `SimpleActivatorMenu.cs`:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class SimpleActivatorMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // An incredibly simple menu which, when given references
        // to gameobjects in the scene
        public GUIText camSwitchButton;
        public GameObject[] objects;


        private int m_CurrentActiveObject;


        private void OnEnable()
        {
            // active object starts from first in array
            m_CurrentActiveObject = 0;
            camSwitchButton.text = objects[m_CurrentActiveObject].name;
        }


        public void NextCamera()
        {
            int nextactiveobject = m_CurrentActiveObject + 1 >= objects.Length ? 0 : m_CurrentActiveObject + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                objects[i].SetActive(i == nextactiveobject);
            }

            m_CurrentActiveObject = nextactiveobject;
            camSwitchButton.text = objects[m_CurrentActiveObject].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a problem?

Comment: is there some sort of output of compiling or running this code? An error message?

Comment: `Why is the GUI components obsolete?` Because, as the error says, they want you to use the new way instead.

Comment: `but it is still having problems.` What are the problems?

Comment: Those messages mean that the author of the class library you are using has marked `GUITexture` and `GUIText` as obsolete and recommends that you use different classes instead.  It's not unusual that replacements like this are not *drop-in replacements* and that you need to update your code.  Your statement *"I tried replacing them with the items given to me in the error, but it is still having problems"* is kind of useless.  We can't guess what problems you are having.  Do you get error messages?  If so, at compile time or at run time?

Comment: This is supposed to be for the Unity project, not just a simple program. Yes, there is 2 errors in the program and I'm still new to Unity, so yeah. Thanks for asking. @Richard

Comment: Class library? I can't find by what you mean class library. I will try though. @Flydog57

Comment: By "class library", I mean the code you are using.  Someone wrote `GUITexture` and `GUIText` and packaged them up somehow.  Then they decided you should use `UI.Image` and `UI.Text` instead.  Go look at the docs for those 4 classes.  Or, show us your error(s) and describe how they appear.

Answer (score 3):

GUIText and Other Elements have been Removed from the Newer Versions of Unity Due to Combability and Some Other Issues!

**Fix for GUI Text**

Make Sure that you Import the Following Line of Statement in your Code:-

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Then, Simply Change from

```
 public GUIText camSwitchButton;
```

to

```
public Text camSwitchButton;
```

**Fixed for GUI Texture**

This Fix Gave Me Some Warning on Other Files But Worked Properly! It Might Be Fixed in the Upcoming Updates of Unity!

Make Sure that you Import the Following Line of Statement in your Code:-

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Then, Change from this Line of Code

```
[RequireComponent(typeof (GUITexture))]
```

to,

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Texture))]
```

Hope So this Helps! I Have Checked it and it works Fine But Just Gave Me Some Warnings which I Don't Care!

But It will be Fine and will be Fixed in Some Upcoming Versions of Unity!

Answer (score 0):

#### Fixed

1. For the `ForcedReset.cs` file change its contents with the following code:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Texture))]
public class ForcedReset : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        // if we have forced a reset ...
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("ResetObject"))
        {
            //... reload the scene
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneAt(0).name);
        }
    }
}
```

2. For the `SimpleActivatorMenu.cs` file change its contents with the following:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class SimpleActivatorMenu : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // An incredibly simple menu which, when given references
        // to gameobjects in the scene
        public Text camSwitchButton;
        public GameObject[] objects;


        private int m_CurrentActiveObject;


        private void OnEnable()
        {
            // active object starts from first in array
            m_CurrentActiveObject = 0;
            camSwitchButton.text = objects[m_CurrentActiveObject].name;
        }


        public void NextCamera()
        {
            int nextactiveobject = m_CurrentActiveObject + 1 >= objects.Length ? 0 : m_CurrentActiveObject + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                objects[i].SetActive(i == nextactiveobject);
            }

            m_CurrentActiveObject = nextactiveobject;
            camSwitchButton.text = objects[m_CurrentActiveObject].name;
        }
    }
}
```